# Métodos Async - retornar string proveniente de UDP

Tags: c#, socket, async, lado-do-cliente

Estou a desenvolver um código cujo o objectivo é enviar um pacote com uma string em broadcast e depois fazer a leitura da resposta (caso haja), no entanto quero criar um método que apenas me retorne a string da resposta.
Tenho o seguinte, baseado no exemplo fornecido pela windows:

```
private async void testUdpSocketServer(string message) {

  DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
  socket.MessageReceived += Socket_MessageReceived;

  //You can use any port that is not currently in use already on the machine. We will be using two separate and random 
  //ports for the client and server because both the will be running on the same machine.
  string serverPort = "1337";
  string clientPort = "1338";

  //Because we will be running the client and server on the same machine, we will use localhost as the hostname.
  Windows.Networking.HostName serverHost = new Windows.Networking.HostName("255.255.255.255");

  //Bind the socket to the clientPort so that we can start listening for UDP messages from the UDP echo server.
  await socket.BindServiceNameAsync(clientPort);

  //Write a message to the UDP echo server.
  Stream streamOut = (await socket.GetOutputStreamAsync(serverHost, serverPort)).AsStreamForWrite();
  StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(streamOut);

  await writer.WriteLineAsync(message);
  await writer.FlushAsync();
}

private async void Socket_MessageReceived(DatagramSocket sender, DatagramSocketMessageReceivedEventArgs args) {
  //Read the message that was received from the UDP echo server.
  Stream streamIn = args.GetDataStream().AsStreamForRead();
  StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(streamIn);
  string message = await reader.ReadLineAsync();
}
```

Agora pretendia desenvolver um método do género para retornar a string utilizando a chamada do método `testUdpSocketServer(string message)`, como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 1):

Se entendi bem, você quer criar um método que faça a chamada assíncrona ao método *testUdpSocketServer*. Isto pode ser realizado de duas formas:

- Adicionar um retorno do tipo "*System.Threading.Tasks.**Task***" na sua função para que possa ser '*awaitable*' :

  `private async Task testUdpSocketServer(string message)
  {
    // código...
  }`

  Assim você poderia chamar o teste utilizando: 
  `await testUdpSocketServer(msg);`
- Utilizar uma ***Task*** que faça o trabalho:

  `Task.Run(async ()=> { await testUdpSocketServer(msg); });`